# asp.net render partial -render ascx page tnto aspx page

Tags: asp.net, render

hey..i am new to asp.net and i want to know 
how to render a partial page (.ascx) into .aspx page 
on a link click

Answer (score 3):

Include the user control file in your ASPX page but set it to invisible:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagName="test" TagPrefix="asp" Src="~/Test.ascx" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:test runat="server" ID="test" Visible="false" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then put a link on your page and when this link is clicked set the visibility of the control to true in the click handler:

```
test.Visible = true;
```

And here's the whole example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ToDD._Default" %>
<%@ Register TagName="test" TagPrefix="asp" Src="~/Test.ascx" %>

<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    protected void ShowClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test.Visible = true;
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:test runat="server" ID="test" Visible="false" />
        <br/>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnShow" runat="server" Text="Show" OnClick="ShowClick" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

UPDATE:

As requested here's the same example using javascript:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagName="test" TagPrefix="asp" Src="~/Test.ascx" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show() {
        document.getElementById('container').style.display='block';
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="container" style="display:none;">
            <asp:test runat="server" ID="test" />
        </div>
        <br/>
        <a href="#" onclick="show();">Show</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer...
but i wanted to use only JavaScript
can you please provide the same with javascript

Comment: after running i am getting this error System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster – 

the error came showing following line highlighted
(i am using MVC)
 <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>

Comment: hey...thanx for the replay 
but theres one problem ...
above code ..is rendering ascx page automatically ...
i want it to be onclick ie manually can you pls help...

i cut runat=server in <asp:test runat="server" ID="test"  />
but after that the 'show' lnk stopped working

pls help